# Compare object property to variable in localstorage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to compare an object property to a variable stored in localstorage using Javascript or Jquery? Here's what I mean...

So I have an object like this:

```
var persons = [
  {
    "firstName": "Dwight",
    "surName": "Stender",
    "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/99.jpg",
    "id": "1"
  }
]
```

And I have a variable stored in localstorage (the name is clickId). Now I want to compare the id from the object to that variable in localstorge. I can print them both to the console so I know they work. But when I try to compare them, it suddenly doesn't work anymore (even though the id and the variable contain the same number). This is how I compared the two:

```
for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    if (persons[i].id == localStorage.clickId) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yay"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "nay"
    };
};
```

**Note 1** I have also tried comparing the two with `===` instead of `==`

**Note 2** the statements to be executed inside the `if...else` are just placeholders for the purpose of explanation

Comment: What is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `localStorage.getItem(key)` to retrieve the object you previously stored. Also note that as `localStorage` can only hold string you'd need to serialise the object before/after saving it. JSON would be ideal for this:

Also note that you can use `some()` to negate the `for` loop, and a ternary to simplify the `if`.

```js
var persons = [{
  "firstName": "Dwight",
  "surName": "Stender",
  "picture": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/99.jpg",
  "id": "1"
}];

var person = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person') || '{}');
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = persons.some(p => p.id == person.clickId) ? "yay" : 'nay';

localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify({
  clickId: 1
}));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pvuyrgj1/)

Comment: So you can't compare them directly? You have to store the localstorage variable inside another variable?

Comment: Yes - the `localStorage` is a dictionary containing key/value pairs. It does not store information in the manner you're expecting. I updated the answer to give you a more complete example too.

Comment: Okay I see, just to be clear: if I have "(clickId, 1)"  already saved in localstorage, it would be enough for me to change the getItem('person') to getItem('clickId')?

Comment: How do I replace the "yay" (if it's true) with the property firstName from the persons object? If I print anything other than plain text, it doesn't show... Is that because of the some() method or because of the shortened if...else statement?

Comment: Does it need to be the `firstName` of the found person? If so that's a fundamental logic change

Comment: Yes, but in my clickId (that is the variable stored in localstorage) the id is saved dynamically. So I have a link for each person and if I click on that link the correct id is stored in that localstorage variable... So I just need to compare that clickId to all the id's in the array and wherever the two id's match I would print the firstName and surName properties

Answer (score 0):

you can use the inArray method of Jquery without need to use the loop

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

Returns index of value in array. Returns - 1 if the array does not contain the value